# Specify different style for Revolution Slider Navigation elements

Tags: html, css, wordpress, revolution-slider

I'm trying to make different bullets navigation for last slide of my page using Revolution slider plugin. Actually the code for  bullets is:

```css
.miko2.tp-bullets {}

.miko2.tp-bullets:before {
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: -10px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  border-radius: 1px;
}

.miko2 .tp-bullet {
  width: 2px;
  height: 90px;
  position: absolute;
  background: #dd3333;
  border: 1px solid white;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.miko2 .tp-bullet:hover,
.miko2 .tp-bullet.selected {
  background: black;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.miko2 .tp-bullet-image {}

.miko2 .tp-bullet-title {}
```

where "miko2" is class for the slide bullets.

Now, I have one slide which requires different styling (contrast reasons). I assigned to that slide already a custom class, but when I try to overwrite style, nothing happens. I tried in both navigation editor and principal CSS window of slider, but can't see it work. "slide3" is custom class for that different slide. I will appreciate any help. Tnx guys :D

```
.miko2 .tp-bullet.slide3 {
    background: white !important;
    border:1px solid white !important;
}
```

Comment: I need to see your HTML. Do you have the page ready?

Comment: No, is not ready nor published. Is there any way to send full HTML of this part? Sorry, I-m a dummy for this. haha

Comment: Use `Ctrl+Shift+I` to see the Dev Tools on Chrome. You can see the HTML associated with the element.